# IEnumerable, IEnumerator, yield

Tags: c#

Форумчане, привет !

Продолжаю разбираться с синтаксисом C#. В очередной раз пересмотрел все источники и понимание так и не пришло. 
Разобрался как работают IEnumerable и IEnumerator: для коллекции необходимо создать некий объект - итератор, который будет осуществлять перебор элементов коллекции. Для этого мы реализуем IEnumerable, который содержит в себе 1 метод- GetEnumerator(). Возвращаемое значение метода типа IEnumerator и явно вызываем GetEnumerator из IEnumerable. IEnumerator содержит в себе 3 метода: двигает индекс, возвращает объект и возвращает указатель на начало коллекции. Понял как работает foreach. НО !
Как и где их наследовать нет понимания. А yield вообще не понимаю что за зверь и с чем его едят.
 Вопросы:

1.Какие классы должны реализовывать IEnumerable и IEnumerator ? Те, которые содержат коллекцию или те, в которых мы будем её перебирать ??

2. В каком месте их реализовывать ? Неужели надо прописывать реализацию всех методов IEnumeratorа ?
3. Почему foreach работает в методе Main без реализации IEnumerable и IEnumerator ?

   ```
   namespace ConsoleApp2
   {
       class Person
       {
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public string LastName { get; set; }
           public int Age { get; set; }

       public Person(int age)
       {
           Age = age;
       }
   }
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           List<Person> newCollection = new List<Person>();
           for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {
               newCollection.Add(new Person(i));
           }

           foreach(Person person in newCollection)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
           }

           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Что такое yield и в каких случаях нам следует его применять ?

Буду благодарен за ответы. В идеале, максимально простым языком на котиках и собачках.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1.Какие классы должны реализовывать IEnumerable и IEnumerator ? Те, которые содержат коллекцию или те, в которых мы будем её перебирать ??

Все, что вы планируете перебирать

> В каком месте их реализовывать ? Неужели надо прописывать реализацию всех методов IEnumeratorа ?

Чтобы реализовать интерфейс, надо отнаследоваться и прописать все методы интерфейса

> Почему foreach работает в методе Main без реализации IEnumerable и IEnumerator ?

Это называется утиная типизация. Foreach может перечислить всё, что имеет метод `GetEnumerator`. Но в вашем примере тут

```
    foreach(Person person in newCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
    }
```

Вы перебираете `List<Person>`, который реализует `IEnumerable`

> Что такое yield и в каких случаях нам следует его применять ?

[yield](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.12.php) вы можете использовать, если ваша последовательность бесконечна или вы не хотите создавать коллекцию в качестве результата. Например вот эта функция возвращает бесконечную последовательность Фибоначчи

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacci()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 1;

    var x=1;
    var y=1;        

    while (true) {
        var tmp = x+y;
        x = y;
        y = tmp;
        yield return tmp;
    }
}
```

Но, так как последовательность вычисляется лениво, то, например, можно взять только первые 10 чисел, которые посчитаются, а остальные не считать.

```
foreach (var rand in GetFibonacci().Take(10))
    Console.WriteLine(rand);
```

На выходе будет

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
```